# Min Value of a 2D Array diagonally? [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently stuck on finding a min value of 2D array diagonal? For example if i had

```
2 1 3
4 5 6
9 8 7
```

I'd want the diagonal min of 2, 5 ,7.
As of now I have a nested for loop that prints 0, honestly my code below is pretty useless but might as well post it.

```
double minD = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
        minD = Math.min(minD, a[row][col]);
        System.out.printf("%5.2f", minD);
```

If anyone can help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `minD` initialized with `0` is the problem. Since `0` is lesser than any of your values, the correct output does not come through.
2. Your code checks for all matrix values, not just the diagonals.

   ```
   int arr[][] = {{2, 1, 3}, {4,5,6}, {9,8,7} };
   int min = arr[0][0];
   for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i][i]<min)
          min = arr[i][i];
   }
   System.out.println(min);
   ```

This code checks just for diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public class ArrayStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] twoArray = {{2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {9, 8, 7}};

        // start with the highest value possible, that way anything that you find
        // in the first loop will be smaller.
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        // loop through the outer arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < twoArray.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            if (twoArray[i][j] < minValue) {
                minValue = twoArray[i][j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(minValue);
    }
}
```

This will traverse the arrays that hold the ints, comparing the value at each inner-arrays index with the value of the int at the same index. So, it will compare the values at twoArray[0][0], twoArray[1][1], and twoArray[2][2] and return the minimum value.